# signalling error from kernel

Tags: opencl

Is there a way for kernel interrupt the task queue and yield control to the host prematurely, flushing the remaining, yet unprocessed tasks?

I am passing output arrays to kernels, of which required size is not known in advance. I am trying to estimate the size, but if it is too small, the kernel should return control to the host, which could re-allocate it or otherwise react. Currently I have the kernel set some flag in a struct which is passed to all kernels, and every kernel checks this error flag when it executes and exits immediately if it is set; this way, the rest of the queue is practically skipped over. I am wondering if there is a better way for this? Can I generate an event from the kernel, for instance?